# Trying to connect categories and users through pivot table i Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

I have users and categories tables and pivot table categorie_users in database. In controller I make that every user can create your own categories and I make check if some category exist and if logged user have that category, he can't create new category with same name and that works fine. So next what I want is 'else' - if category exist and logged user don't have that category but he want to create it - in that case I want to connect that category which already exist and that user. Other words - I want to, let's say, category 'Music' to be just one category with that name for all future users. This is so complicated so any suggestions will appreciate. Thanks.
This is my CategoriesController.php

```
   public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = Sentinel::getUser();

    $category = Categories::where('name', $request->name)->get();

    foreach ($category as $cat){
        $user = CategorieUser::where('categorie_id',$cat->id)->where('user_id', $user->id);
    }

    if($category->count() > 0){
        if($user->count() > 0){
            return redirect()->route('categories.index');
        }
        else{

            /*THIS IS THAT 'else' FROM ABOVE QUESTION*/

        }
    }
    else{
        $categories = new Categories();
        $categories->name = $request->name;
        $categories->sections_id = $request->sections_id;
        $categories->save();
        $categories->users()->sync([$user->id]);
    }       
    session()->flash('success', "New category '{$categories->name}' has been created.");
    return redirect()->route('categories.index');
}
```

And this is my model Categories.php

```
   <?php

    namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Categories extends Model
    {
       protected $table = 'categories';

      public function sections()
      {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Sections');
      }

      public function users()
      {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Users', 'categorie_user','categorie_id','user_id');
     }

   }
```

This is model Users.php

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Users extends Model
    {
         protected $table = 'users';


      public function categories()
      {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Categories', 'categorie_user','user_id','categorie_id');
      }

  }
```

And this is pivot model CategorieUser.php (which I must create that I can go through foreach loop)

```
   <?php

    namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class CategorieUser extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'categorie_user';


      public function categories(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Categories', 'categorie_id');
      }

    }
```

Comment: categorie_users is not a pivot table, it is called a junction or associative table. Pivot table is for transposing field values as columns.

Comment: And it is reallynot that complicated: place a unique constraint on the category names. If a user tries to create a category that already exists, then you'll get a duplicate key error back from the database. In that case retrieve the existing category's id by name and insert the current user's id with the category id in your junction table.

Comment: I have been added unique on the category names and indeed return me duplicate key error back from the database.  But I tried to wrote code but I can't make it to work, all my attempts fails. I'm totally newbie, can you show me, please? Thanks for help and I'm sorry if I bothering.

Comment: 1) we help you to fix your code, we will not write it for you. Update the question with your best attempt and describe the error or unexpected behaviour you encountered. 2) if you are such a newbie, then are you sure that you need to start with MVC and ORM? Learn how to write simple algorithms first...